# Array sorting printing and summing

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, printing

What would be the simplest method to print this array broken down into each mobile phone as a product number, name department etc, and then re print the same information sorted by product name. I have tried a couple different methods and am already passed the turn in date for the assignment but still need to figure it out for upcoming assignment this weekend. When I try to implement the comparator on MobilePhone class it forces me to make it abstract or use @override but I can't figure out where or what to override to make it work because the abstract class causes a multitude of other problems.

```
package InventoryPro2;

import java.util.*;

class MobilePhone {

    private double productNumber; // Variables
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private double unitsInStock;
    private double unitPrice;

    public MobilePhone() {
        this(0.0, "", "", 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    public MobilePhone(double productNumber, String name, String department,
            double unitsInStock, double unitPrice) { //assign variables
        this.productNumber = productNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
        this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public double getproductNumber() { // retrieve values
        return productNumber;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getdepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public double getunitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public double getunitsInStock() {
        return unitsInStock;
    }

    public void setproductNumber(double productNumber) {
        this.productNumber = productNumber;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setdepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void setunitPrice(double unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public void setunitsInStock(double unitsInStock) {
        this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    }

    public double gettotalInv() {
        return getunitPrice() * getunitsInStock();
    }
}

public class InventoryPro2 {

    MobilePhone mobilephone = new MobilePhone();

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        System.out.println("Mobile Phone Inventory Program");
        System.out.println();//skips a line

        MobilePhone[] phones = new MobilePhone[5];


        phones[0] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[0].setproductNumber(1);
        phones[0].setname("Motorola");
        phones[0].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[0].setunitPrice(150.10);
        phones[0].setunitsInStock(98);

        phones[1] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[1].setproductNumber(2);
        phones[1].setname("Samsung");
        phones[1].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[1].setunitPrice(199.99);
        phones[1].setunitsInStock(650);

        phones[2] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[2].setproductNumber(3);
        phones[2].setname("Nokia");
        phones[2].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[2].setunitPrice(200.25);
        phones[2].setunitsInStock(125);

        phones[3] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[3].setproductNumber(4);
        phones[3].setname("LG");
        phones[3].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[3].setunitPrice(100.05);
        phones[3].setunitsInStock(200);

        phones[4] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[4].setproductNumber(5);
        phones[4].setname("IPhone");
        phones[4].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[4].setunitPrice(299.99);
        phones[4].setunitsInStock(150);

        System.out.println("Order of inventory before sorting:");
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

(Also, what is the best way to take just one piece of information out of each part of the array such as the totalInv and total all of those numbers to print?) Do I have unnecessary code here or have I done everything right thus far? I have to say that learning this coding language in an online format has not been a very enjoyable experience thus far..

Comment: Some kind of Map, maybe a TreeMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to sort by name

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class AppInventoryPro2 {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        System.out.println("Mobile Phone Inventory Program");
        System.out.println();// skips a line

        MobilePhone[] phones = new MobilePhone[5];

        phones[0] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[0].setproductNumber(1);
        phones[0].setname("Motorola");
        phones[0].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[0].setunitPrice(150.10);
        phones[0].setunitsInStock(98);

        phones[1] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[1].setproductNumber(2);
        phones[1].setname("Samsung");
        phones[1].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[1].setunitPrice(199.99);
        phones[1].setunitsInStock(650);

        phones[2] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[2].setproductNumber(3);
        phones[2].setname("Nokia");
        phones[2].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[2].setunitPrice(200.25);
        phones[2].setunitsInStock(125);

        phones[3] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[3].setproductNumber(4);
        phones[3].setname("LG");
        phones[3].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[3].setunitPrice(100.05);
        phones[3].setunitsInStock(200);

        phones[4] = new MobilePhone();
        phones[4].setproductNumber(5);
        phones[4].setname("IPhone");
        phones[4].setdepartment("Electronics");
        phones[4].setunitPrice(299.99);
        phones[4].setunitsInStock(150);

        System.out.println("Order of inventory before sorting:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(phones));

        Arrays.sort(phones, new Comparator<MobilePhone>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MobilePhone mp1, MobilePhone mp2) {
                return mp1.getname().compareTo(mp2.getname());
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Order of inventory after sorting by name:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(phones));
    }
}

class MobilePhone {

    private double productNumber; // Variables
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private double unitsInStock;
    private double unitPrice;

    public MobilePhone() {
        this(0.0, "", "", 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    public MobilePhone(double productNumber, String name, String department,
            double unitsInStock, double unitPrice) { // assign variables
        this.productNumber = productNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
        this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public double getproductNumber() { // retrieve values
        return productNumber;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getdepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public double getunitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public double getunitsInStock() {
        return unitsInStock;
    }

    public void setproductNumber(double productNumber) {
        this.productNumber = productNumber;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setdepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void setunitPrice(double unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public void setunitsInStock(double unitsInStock) {
        this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    }

    public double gettotalInv() {
        return getunitPrice() * getunitsInStock();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MobilePhone [productNumber=" + productNumber + ", name=" + name
                + ", department=" + department + ", unitsInStock="
                + unitsInStock + ", unitPrice=" + unitPrice + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Still wants me to make the class abstract to implement the Comparator. Which causes a problem in the InventoryPro2 class because it doesn't allow me to use the information from MobilePhone class for the array

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. This code works in jdk-7. Create AppInventoryPro2 class, copy-paste the code into it and run.

Comment: It does indeed. Only thing I need it to do is print them on seperate lines. \n I think but where in that code would this work? Also I was putting "implements Comparator" on the class name that's what the problem was. Wasn't aware that it could be used without doing so.

Comment: 1. To print on separate lines, as a quick fix replace [return "MobilePhone] with [return "\n  MobilePhone], otherwise you will need iterate here [System.out.println(Arrays.toString(phones));] and add line ends; 2. "implements Comparator" would work too but it allows the only comparison rule (which can be overridden as shown in the code).

Answer (score 0):

1 - To print content of `MobilePhone` class: Override default `toString` method like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MobilePhone [productNumber=" + productNumber +
    ", name=" + name + ']'; // add more info if needed
}
```

2 - To allow sorting by name: Have `MobilePhone` class implement `Comparable` interface like 
this:

```
class MobilePhone implements Comparable {
  ...

    @Override 
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        MobilePhone m = (MobilePhone) o; 
        return (this.name.compareTo(o.name));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** To print your array of `MobilePhone` object you can do:

```
System.out.printf("Phones: %s%n", Arrays.toString(phones));
```

Comment: Would I use a for loop for the printing to use all 5 sections of the array and print one piece of information from each to make the 5 mobile phones print?

Comment: @SadNoob: Edited my answer to show that. Basically you will need: `System.out.printf("Phones: %s%n", Arrays.toString(phones));` to print all elements of your array of MobilePhone objects.